# Ordered list alignment with counter-increment

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a simple ordered list which is not aligned properly if list item has long text.

https://jsfiddle.net/rkmv3rn3/6/

```css
.page-left-bar {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

ol {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.handbook-page ol {
  color: #687074;
  counter-reset: item;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  color: #687074;
}

ol li {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

ol li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #687074;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h1>LIST OL  child list alignment</h1>
<div class="page-left-bar">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="#home">Sub menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">Sub menu long name</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Sub menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">Sub menu</a></li>
    </ol>
    <li><a href="#about">About my company vision and mission</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>


<h1>
Normal List </h1>
<div class="page-left-bar">
 <ol>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Long  menuame </a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About my company vision and mission</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

How to align list so that if text is long, they are left aligned properly if list text moves down to second line.

Comment: not clear to me, but I think you need this `ol li a{display: inline-block;}` it won't let text break down.

Comment: I tried that before before it breaks list

Comment: not for me, look this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkmv3rn3/7/)

Comment: link doesnt worlk broken link

Comment: If you don't want the line to break, you can use the CSS `white-space: nowrap` property, however, I am not sure if the output is desirable, as the text will go outside the boundaries of the main div, see my [jsfiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/0eLggtku/)

Comment: @jiff, anchor text for point 3.2 shows below 3.2 in your fiddle also

Comment: @Pualie_d, This list is different than one in the duplicate question, in this example we are using Counter `content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;`

Comment: @jiff, You increased with of container, Width should be fixed `width: 200px;1

Comment: @ketan, Can you please point me to the changes you made.. add this as a solution i will mark it

Comment: I don't understand, you want fixed `200px` width and want text don't break in new line?

Comment: Vote to open it, so that you can post your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can do following way.

Give `display: table-row;` to `ol li` and `display: table-cell;` to `ol li a`

```
ol li {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

ol li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #687074;
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rkmv3rn3/10/)**